Why is Cgd4 part of CL? Smith Microelectronics Differential Amplifier Frequency Response
Figure 10.37 is the small signal analysis of Gm of the differential amplifier. The analysis combines all the capacitors in the MOSFETs into Cm and CL. I'm asking for the formula of CL.
The textbook gives the formula of CL and Cm in equation 10.133 and 10.134.
I tried to explain the formula of CL and Cm, and I encountered a problem when I'm deriving CL. Of all the capacitors, only Cgd4 doesn't connect node B to ground. Why is Cgd4 part of the capacitor load?



Just a wild guess.
Cgd4 can be approximated to the output via the miller cap as almost the same as its own value. That's probably why he did this approximation.
Also note that cgd4 is grounded if one is to compute the gm, because the output would be grounded then.
Need more context from the book as well...

My classmate says that Vg3 is close to 0. Hence, K in Millers Theorem should be very large, which makes (Z/1-(1/K)) = Z? Wondering why Vg3 is close to 0.
Well the textbook just throws 10.134 without explaining. Its at smith microelectronics 7e page 773.

@DCtimeMc I don't see that. If Vg3 is close to 0 then Q1 would be off.

Figure 10.37 (a) is the small signal analysis of the differential amplifier when two inputs are complementary (one is vid/2 the other is -vid/2). In this case, the source of Q1 and Q2 is zero. In large signal analysis its not necessary zero. Hence, it wont be off when Vg3 is zero in small signal analysis. I might be wrong sometimes :).
